# Host multiple websites on same python app

Tags: python, django

I want to start make a django app, but i want to know if it's possible to use same "core" to host multiple sites.each site will just have a unique conf file (templates to use, db name, meta info, etc). what will be the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Django sites framework.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) Hope that yo are doing fine .

I'm not that good in python but I guess that you could get some help from a previous similar question through this link

https://scottlinux.com/2014/04/03/how-to-host-multiple-django-or-python-apps-on-the-same-host-with-nginx-and-gunicorn/

Hope that my answer helped in a way or clarified your intent

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, a Django app is a WSGI app. Many decent WSGI servers support running multiple WSGI apps simultaneously. For instance, uWSGI supports multiple WSGI apps using "Emperor mode". Check it out: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Emperor.html